# PGF plot legend placement error

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I am currently trying to relocate the legend of my plot at the top left corner. But as soon as I set the command `[legend pos=north west]`, the legend is relocated, but the grid lines are not rendered anymore and the axis range is completely off.

[image: error?]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \begin{axis}[legend pos=north west]
    [
        grid=major,
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=3,
        ymin=-2,
        xmax=3,
        axis x line=middle,
        ytick={-1, 0, 1},
        ymax=2,
        axis y line=middle,
        legend cell align={left}
    ]
        \addplot%0.1
        [
            Dandelion,%
            line width=2pt,
            mark=none,
            samples=100,
            domain=-10:10,
        ]
        (x,{x*(1/(1+exp(-0.1*x)))});     \addlegendentry{$\beta = 0.1$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry! I edited the MWE

Answer (score 2):

The main issue is that you have closing `]` after `legend pos=north west`, so the other options get ignored. As Joule V points out, this key doesn't yield the desired position. The legend can be placed with `legend style={at={(axis cs:0,2)},...`.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \begin{axis}[grid=major,
        xmin=-5,
        xmax=3,
        ymin=-2,
        xmax=3,
        %axis x line=middle,
        ytick={-1, 0, 1},
        ymax=2,
         legend style={at={(axis cs:0,2)},
        anchor=north west,outer sep=3pt},
        %axis y line=middle,
        legend cell align={left},
        axis lines=middle,
    ]
        \addplot%0.1
        [
            Dandelion,%
            line width=2pt,
            mark=none,
            samples=100,
            domain=-5:3,
        ]
        (x,{x*(1/(1+exp(-0.1*x)))});     
    \addlegendentry{$\beta = 0.1$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]